# How can I automate Splunk iterations using REST API

Tags: rest, splunk, splunk-sdk

I was looking for an endpoint to be able to get amount of available Events in "Splunk/App Search & Reporting/What to Search"
I would also appreciate endpoint to be able to get this kind of info provided clicking over "Data Summary" button and filling filter.

Please see attached file to more details. I was looking for a REST API endpoint which provided me 1703436 number, I know this is "real time", but interested in any case :)

I'm automating some stuff and I do really need these events info in order to be able to couple to my script

Thanks a lot for your attention

[an image worth a thousand words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP1xP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem using two steps. 
First creating a search job of `| eventcount` and second retrieving this job number to get result for it. 
In pseudo code
`job_id = $(curl -u admin:admin -k https://localhost:8089/services/search/jobs -d search='| eventcount' | grep -oP '(?<=<sid>).+(?=<\/)')`
`curl -u admin:admin -k https://localhost:8089/services/search/jobs/$job_id/results/ --get -d output_mode=csv | grep -oP '\d+'")`